# How to render data on view without having to refresh the page in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Now I save information on the `SessionStorage` and then I try to show it in my view, the problem is when I try to show it on the view, it seems like the rendering of the HTML is faster due to the saving on the storage its made by an asynchronous call, I know it's difficult to understand and that's why I will explain my code right below

Here you will see my `ngOnInit` that will call first the function `getIfPersonWasAlreadyScanned` that is the one who makes the asynchronous call, after that on `this.specificParticipant` I will save the data that was set to the `sessionStorage` and that is the one that will be show in the view

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userLogged'));
    this.userSettings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userSettings'));
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
      this.getIfPersonWasAlreadyScanned(this.user.clientId,this.user.projectId,this.id);
      this.specificParticipant = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('AllScanned'));
      this.getParticipant(this.id);
    });
  }
```

This function is the one that set the data to the `sessionStorage`

```js
getIfPersonWasAlreadyScanned(clientId,projectId,personId){
    this.loadCompleted = false;
    this.deviceService.getIfPersonWasAlreadyScanned(clientId,projectId,personId)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.participantScans = res;
        sessionStorage.setItem('AllScanned', JSON.stringify(this.participantScans));
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

This is the code inside of my HTML as you can see I use an `ngFor` for iterate inside of the array that is on the `specificParticipant` variable, the problem is when I display this HTML the information its already on the `sessionStorage` but not here I have to refresh the page to actually see it on the HTML, how can I solve this?

```js
<ng-container *ngFor="let participant of specificParticipant">
                <mat-card class="width-75 mb-20 mr-20 ml-20">
                    <mat-card-content class="width-75" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                        <th class="w-320 shocklogic-font text-dark text-center">Delegate Scans</th>
                        <div fxLayout="column">
                            <mat-card-header>
                                <mat-card-title class="participants-card-title">
                                </mat-card-title>
                                <mat-card-subtitle class="participants-card-subtitle"><strong>Last Scanned:</strong>{{participant.Last_Scanned}}</mat-card-subtitle>
                                <mat-card-subtitle class="participants-card-subtitle"><strong>Scan Result:</strong>{{participant.Scan_Result}}</mat-card-subtitle>
                                <mat-card-subtitle class="participants-card-subtitle"><strong>Device Name:</strong>{{participant.Device_Name}}</mat-card-subtitle>
                                <mat-card-subtitle class="participants-card-subtitle"><strong>Activity Name:</strong>{{participant.Activity_Name}}</mat-card-subtitle>
                            </mat-card-header>
                            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                <button class="force-btn" (click)="deleteParticipantScan(participant.DeviceScan_Id)" mat-stroked-button>Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card-content>
                </mat-card>
            </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is occurring because

```
this.specificParticipant = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('AllScanned'));
```

is getting called prior to the conclusion of

```
this.deviceService.getIfPersonWasAlreadyScanned(clientId,projectId,personId)
```

within `getIfPersonWasAlreadyScanned()`.

---

You need to return an observable from `getIfPersonWasAlreadyScanned()` and subscribe to that.

```
this.getIfPersonWasAlreadyScanned(this.user.clientId,this.user.projectId,this.id).subscribe(() => {
   // we now know that AllScanned has been successfully update. 
   this.specificParticipant = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('AllScanned'));
});
```

Comment: Putting the `this.specificParticipant = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('AllScanned'));` inside of that function that I already had was the answer

Answer (score 0):

Pass a callback function to getIfPersonWasAlreadyScanned. Once the async process ends, initiate the callback.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    var self = this;
    this.loading = true;  // use this variable to show a loading screen
    this.getIfPersonWasAlreadyScanned(this.user.clientId, this.user.projectId, this.id, function(){
        self.specificParticipant = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('AllScanned'));
        self.getParticipant(self.id);
        self.loading = false;
    });
}



getIfPersonWasAlreadyScanned(clientId,projectId,personId){
    this.loadCompleted = false;
    this.deviceService.getIfPersonWasAlreadyScanned(clientId, projectId, personId, cb)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.participantScans = res;
        sessionStorage.setItem('AllScanned', 
        JSON.stringify(this.participantScans));
        cb();
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        cb();
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: This is not the ideal solution as the `this` context of your callback will change.